# Paint textures on object in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am working on a game and I have made my own models in blender. I have made a ground plane in blender but I had some issues when trying to get the texture in to unity and since it is a simple texture I figured I could just paint it in unity. So basically what I want to do is paint on a grass texture on the model and then paint some paths using a sand soil texture. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I used [InkPainter](https://github.com/EsProgram/InkPainter) for a project, but it's create a texture in runTime and paint it with a brush texture passed in component with the color passed in component IDE too. It's very useful and had a way to save the texture in a bitmap file (or png or jpg), but when i install this in my project I've some problems like the component not painting some object that doesn't have the shader informed in the tool. I do a upgrade to work with default shader but I need to push it yet.
I found others tools but lots of then are payed.

[blog of the creator of InkPainter](https://esprogram.github.io/InkPainterDocument/)